# How to use data from one DataBase to connect to another one in PHP and MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, database, session, connection

So to sum thing up:
I want to create a single login page that redirects to a page that will be populated by information from a specific/personal database. 
To do this I have created a database that holds the information of all my users (including the specific connection information to their personal database this means DataBase -Host- -User- -Password- -Name-)
This central user dataBase ("DB A") will validate the user at login, then when redirected to the WebApp main page will provide the connection information to the personal database ("DB B") that will hold their WebApp data.

I have tried pulling the connection information from the login page and storing it in $_SESSION. This gives error.
Have tried converting the $_SESSION into (string). Gives error.

I have tried fetching for the information with a query on the WebApp main page and then assigning the information to variables and using those variables in a "mysqli_connect()" function. This gives error.
Have tried converting into an array. Gives error.

All the time the error is:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'username'@'10.2.1.19'

As far as my research has gone, this is due to the fact that the connection information is a resource that cannot be stored into $_SESSION. But what about fetching for the data using a query?

Can someone help me please.

Comment: separate db per user is almost allwasy a bad idea.

Comment: But I need to keep separate databases due to sensitive information uploaded by the clients. 
Clients don't like it when they share data bases with other clients.

Comment: clients wont know, you think Facebook has a db for every individual\company

Comment: Insane idea. Clients don't like it. Those clients are using memory addresses that were in use by other clients data a second before. Do they like that? Or is it the lack of confidence in a multi-tenant setup that is really driving it.

Comment: Are you saying it is a bad idea to use $_SESSION. 
And a multi-tenant set up is exactly what I am aiming for.